# How can I monitor different OpenMP threads in real time?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have written some code for an optimisation algorithm which I have parallelised using OpenMP in order to speed it up, however now it is almost impossible to see what is going on with the different threads as they all print to `std::cout`. I was wondering if there was a way that I can send the output to different terminal windows (i am using Linux Mint OS) so that I am able to monitor the different threads separately?

A very basic version of the code I am running is:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i < N_ITER; ++i){
    solve(seed_solution);
}
```

here, `seed_solution` is an initial feasible solution to the problem, and `solve()` is a stochastic optimisation algorithm which generates neighbouring solutions to the seed solution used as input.

`solve()` has several processes that output to `std::cout` but because the threads are all running simultaneously, it is impossible to keep track of what is happening when. I can make it go:

```
std::cout << "thread(" << omp_get_thread_num() << "): " <<
```

for every line but then I end up with an output like:

```
thread(0): text text text
thread(2): text text text text text
thread(1): text text text text
thread(1): text text text text text text
thread(3): text text text
thread(0): text text text text text text text
```

which is incredibly hard to parse, especially when you are watching it in real-time, trying to find any bugs or parameters to change.

my solution to the problem was to output each thread to a separate file like this:

```
std::vector<std::ofstream*> out_streams;
for (int i = 0; i < omp_get_max_threads(); ++i){
std::ofstream* out_stream = new std::ofstream("thread_" + std::to_string(i) + ".out");
out_streams.push_back(out_stream);
}

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i < N_ITER; ++i){
    solve(seed_solution, out_streams[omp_get_thread_num()]);
}
```

and then within `solve()` (which has been modified to take a `std::ofstream` pointer as one of its arguments) instead of printing to `std::cout`, print to the `out_stream` pointer.

This works to give me separate files for all of my threads, but unless I want to wait until all computation is completed and review the output files then, I have to close the files and open them again to refresh the contents. Is there any way that I can monitor these threads separately, in real-time? Can anyone suggest a Linux application that auto-refreshes text files, so that I can have them open in separate windows maybe?

Comment: you can simply put locks when use `cout`.

Comment: `tail` (as suggested by @NoThatIsTeal) followed by `grep` to filter the output stream, one console window for each thread, each with an appropriate filter.  It might work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `tail -f`:

`$ tail -f foo`

From the tail manpage on my machine:

> -f      The -f option causes tail to not stop when end of file is reached, but rather to wait for additional data to be appended to the input.  The -f option is ignored if the standard input is a pipe, but not
>                if it is a FIFO.

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303623/how-can-i-view-the-file-output-of-a-program-in-a-text-file-as-its-being-populat